# Strange PHP date comparison error

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I don't get the expected results. Basically I just want to compare two dates (in unix format) and show the difference in months/days/hours/..

This is an excerpt of the code: UPDATE -- added more code

```
$date = mktime($hour, $min, 0, $month, $day, $year);
$now = time();


echo 'OKdate' . $date . ' now ' . $now . ' now < date ' . ($now < $date);

if($now < $date)
{
    $difference = $date - $now;

    $seconds2 = date('s', $difference);
    $minutes2 = date('i', $difference);
    $hours2 = date('G', $difference) - 1;
    $days2 = date('j', $difference) - 1;
    $months2 = date('n', $difference) - 1;
    $years2 =  date('Y', $difference) - 1970;

    $timeleft = '';
    if(!empty($years2))
        $timeleft .= $years2 . ' year' . ($years2 > 1 ? 's ' : ' ');

    if(!empty($months2))
        $timeleft .= $months2 . ' month' . ($months2 > 1 ? 's ' : ' ');

    if(!empty($days2))
        $timeleft .= $days2 . ' day' . ($days2 > 1 ? 's ' : ' ');

    if(!empty($hours2))
        $timeleft .= $hours2 . ' hour' . ($hours2 > 1 ? 's ' : ' ');

    if(!empty($minutes2))
        $timeleft .= $minutes2 . ' minute' . ($minutes2 > 1 ? 's ' : ' ');

    if(!empty($seconds2))
        $timeleft .= $seconds2 . ' second' . ($seconds2 > 1 ? 's ' : ' ');

    $template = $templates->get('postcountdown_post', 1, 0);
    eval('$temp = "' . $template . '";');
    return $temp;
}
```

Now, this is shown on the page:

```
date = 1437950400 
now  = 1437935682 
now < date = true
```

Strangely enough, this is the result I'm getting by echoing the data:

```
11 months 30 days 22 hours 05 minutes 18 seconds left
```

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Added more code --- FYI: the template contains {$timeleft} inside. So the eval just makes sure the {$timeleft} is evaluated and filled in by PHP.

**Current problem:** the code does seem to work, but not in the application. For some strange reason I'm getting
$difference = 12076;
And the date function of PHP used on this is giving me: -1 years, 11 months, ....
Another strange thing is: it does work with some dates; but with others it doesn't and makes it -1 years. -- or maybe there really is a flaw in my code that I'm not seeing?

```
date 1437954000 
now 1437942191 
now < date true
diff 11809
// $...2 variables
seconds 49 
mins 16 
hours 21 
days 30 
months 11 
years -1
```

Comment: Why do you think your result is wrong?

Comment: All code above is correct. Might it be that you overwrite the values for $seconds, $minutes, etc.? because here it shows what it should show: `0 year 0 month 0 day 4 hour 05 min 18 sec `

Comment: @Jeffrey Wow.. Strangest thing ever. I guess so!! But it's really not obvious where, I'll have to take a deep look at this one; thanks for letting me know!!

Comment: If you provide more code we can help, otherwise just search for the variables or... better yet, use different names in the above part of the code! Than you can be sure that other parts of the code arent harmed.

Comment: @Jeffrey could you have a look? I renamed to variables to $minutes2, $...2 etc; but it didn't fix it. The template evaluated only contains {$timeleft}. Thanks! :)

I found a clue to the problem by echoing all the $....2 variables =>
seconds 15 mins 32 hours 21 days 30 months 11 years -1

Comment: The above code is all correct. Some notes: use `$now = time();` (not `mktime()` when you provide no parameters. Also $hours should be $hours2. Though, that is not the cause of the problem. What happens in `$templates->get('postcountdown_post', 1, 0)`? And note that `$timeleft` is a local variable and might not be accessible in $templates!

Comment: @Jeffrey the template is evaluated into $temp, so the $timeleft is filled in into the template--this new template is returned to the system to be used. That part works great. I did the small changes you said.. But I still don't understand it. Somehow years = -1; months = 11. Is PHP's date function working bad on this input? It's so strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84324/discussion-between-jeffrey-and-kevin-van-ryckegem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above works as expected on my system. The date function might however behave stange when the location is not set in the ini file. In PHP you can set the server timezone using:

```
date_default_timezone_set ( "Europe/Brussels" );
```

Other timezones can be found here [Timezone Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$now = 1437950400;
$date  = 1437935682; 

if($now > $date) {

$difference = $now - $date;

$seconds = date('s', $difference);
$minutes = date('i', $difference);
$hours = date('G', $difference) - 1;
$days = date('j', $difference) - 1;
$months = date('n', $difference) - 1;
$years =  date('Y', $difference) - 1970;

echo $years . ' Years ' 
    . $months . ' Months '
    . $days . ' Day '
    . $hours . ' Hours '
    . $minutes . ' Minutes '
    . $seconds . ' Seconds ';
}
```

Comment: It does work, but it's actually no different from my code. Thanks for the help though; but something else is causing this strange answer. (seconds 15 mins 32 hours 21 days 30 months 11 years -1)

Comment: Ok this is strange, I just uploaded the code on a phpfiddle and it looks like I have the same result as you but on my local server the code works perfectly fine

Comment: Setting the default timezone fixes this, the answer has been selected :).